# How to test @login_required view in django

Tags: django, python-unittest

I've a django view which has @login_required decorator then it renders html file with context and I'm trying test it's function whether the context is in response

```
@login_required
def my_view(request):
   #code goes here
   context={'name':name}
   return render(request, home.html, context)

class TestEmployer(TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.client.login(username='1', password='Pass@123')

    def test_list_employer(self):
        url = reverse(my_view)
        response = self.client.post(url, follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIn('name', response.context)
```

So @login_required decorator blocking me to test the function and asserts an error with 'name' not in signin html page

Comment: Does the user with username `1` actually exist in the test database? If it exists: I find it easier to use `self.client.force_login(user)` in my tests as I don't have to worry about credentials.

Answer (score 0):

`@login_required` means that function `my_view` wont be accessible until you're logged in. you have to pass login url like this to redirect to your login function in case user tries to access that function without loggin in. `@login_required(login_url="/your_login_view/")`